# Angular pdf display: SafeValue must use [property]=binding

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting 'SafeValue must use [property]=binding' error/warning when trying to display a pdf. I'm not sure why as I am using binding. Here is my code.

```
getSafeUrl() {
 return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.pdfSrc)+"?bearer "+this.token;     
}

<iframe [src]="getSafeUrl()" frameborder="0" *ngIf="pdfSrc"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` with the `[innerHTML]`

```
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.pdfSrc + "?bearer "+this.token);     

<div [innerHTML]="getSafeUrl()"  *ngIf="pdfSrc"></div>
```

Comment: This prints out text and does not display the pdf